# Does the warning "Simultaneous accesses to parameter 'self' ..." really apply here?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, xcode9

I wrote an extension to `Array` that allows me to pop the last element and instantly add it to another array:

```
extension Array {

    mutating func popLast(to otherArray: inout [Element]) -> Element? {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return nil }
        return otherArray.appendAndReturn(self.popLast()!)
    }

    mutating func appendAndReturn(_ element: Element) -> Element {
        self.append(element)
        return element
    }

}
```

This simple example in playground works like a charm:

```
var newNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var usedNumbers: [Int] = []

newNumbers.popLast(to: &usedNumbers)
print(usedNumbers) // [9]

for _ in newNumbers {
    newNumbers.popLast(to: &usedNumbers)
}

print(usedNumbers) // [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

But using the extension inside of a struct (code after the warning) gives me this warning:

> Simultaneous accesses to parameter 'self', but modification requires
>   exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable

```
struct Test {

    var newNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    var usedNumbers: [Int] = []

    mutating func getNewNumber() -> Int? {
        return newNumbers.popLast(to: &usedNumbers)
    }

}
```

It is only a warning and my app runs just fine with the expected behavior, but I'm curious if there really is a danger here. Looking at [SE-0176](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md#arrays), I understand the goal of the warning, if I were to use it to pop the last element from the same array I append it to, because copy-on-write could mess that up. And so I guess it's related to the struct. But using it on two different arrays inside the same struct, I see no danger. **Am I missing something and is there a way to write the extension that would circumvent the potential problem?**

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR The provided playground code is exactly what I do in the app. I just use another type of element there which doesn't add value to the question.

Comment: The provided code does not cause the warning message, so there must be something else in how you use it in your app. A MCVE is a (self-contained) piece of code that anybody can copy/paste into Xcode to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinR I know you want to help, but when I just copied the exact code from playground into my project, it gives me the warning, so I can't provide any better MCVE. As mentioned in the question: There is no warning in playground, only in a project (which is weird for me, too). [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/zR2Mf)

Comment: I have copied your above code into main.swift of a Xcode 9 beta 2 project and get no warning. Your code in the screenshot is not what you posted in the question.

Comment: Are `newNumbers` and `usedNumbers` member variables of a struct? That would explain the mention of ther access to `self`.

Comment: @MartinR okay, seems like I simplified the code too much. The warning appears after using it within a struct - and now in playground, too. I'm updating the code above ... sorry for that!

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist yes, I just realized that, too. So the problem is, that it uses copy-on-write on the whole struct, I guess? But isn't it nevertheless safe if the whole function gets run inside a copy of the struct? I honestly think it should, but I don't know ...

Comment: From SE-0176: *" However, note that modifying part of a value type still requires exclusive access to the entire value, ..."*

Comment: From the *Value types* section of the [SE-0176 Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md): Calling a method on a value type is an access to the entire value because [it's assumed] that a method might read or write an arbitrary part of the value. [...] note that modifying part of a value type still requires exclusive access to the entire value, and that acquiring that access might itself prevent overlapping accesses.

Comment: Yes, thanks guys and sorry again for the confusion at first. I thought I had narrowed my code down to the easiest to understand example and hadn't realized the importance of the `struct` here.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see how OP's example conflicts with "*note that modifying part of a value type still requires exclusive access to the entire value*" – we *have* exclusive access to the entire value, we're inside a `mutating` method. And "*Accesses to different stored properties of a struct or different elements of a tuple are allowed to overlap*", so having simultaneous write access for `newNumbers` & `usedNumbers` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Indeed, the proposal's example of `modifying(&object.pair) { pair in swap(&pair.x, &pair.y) }` actually doesn't compile, because the compiler thinks that simultaneous write access to `pair.x` and `pair.y` in the closure conflicts.

Comment: Relevant bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Your code now works without modification.

As @Hamish noted in the comments below, this [**was a bug**](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5119) that is now fixed in the version of Swift which shipped with Xcode 9 beta 3.  I also verified that it works at the [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl) which is using *Linux x86_64* build *Swift Dev. 4.0 (Jul 13, 2017)*.

---

As you figured out in the comments, the problem is that you need exclusive access to the struct in order to mutate it, but you're passing a reference to part of the struct to the inout parameter.  This is apparently supposed to work since you're accessing different parts of the structure, but [**due to a bug**](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5119) the compiler is too strict here.

The warning suggests copying to a local variable.  Since your return is complicated, I have used a `defer` statement to return the copy of `newNumbers` to `newNumbers` to avoid having to store the result of the call in a temporary variable:

```
struct Test {

    var newNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    var usedNumbers: [Int] = []

    mutating func getNewNumber() -> Int? {
        var newNumbersCopy = newNumbers
        defer { newNumbers = newNumbersCopy }
        return newNumbersCopy.popLast(to: &usedNumbers)
    }

}
```

---

You could also choose to fix it by making a copy of the `usedNumbers`:

```
mutating func getNewNumber() -> Int? {
    var usedNumbersCopy = usedNumbers
    defer { usedNumbers = usedNumbersCopy }
    return newNumbers.popLast(to: &usedNumbersCopy)
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a possible fix (as you mentioned we noticed in the comments that my problem is indeed due to a bug). My whole intention writing the extension was to shorten the code while maintaining readability, so I'm going without my extension for now, since a readable solution seems only achievable in 3 lines in the meantime.

Comment: It looks like a fix is already in the pipe.  I just thought it was worth mentioning that defer could be used to allow your return to still work without having to save the result in a temporary variable.

Comment: Another possible workaround using a modified version of the `modifying` function from the proposal: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/739bf50250af2ccbb2137262c790a57e (why this particular case doesn't trigger the static enforcement, idk).

Comment: Interesting @Hamish.  I think it avoids the warning because of the way `inout` works.  This essentially works the same way under the covers as my first solution.  A copy of `newNumbers` is made going into `modifying` and the result is written back to `newNumbers` on the way out.  When `popLast(to:)` is called, they aren't operating on the same structure.

Comment: @vacawama But then by that logic, OP's code is no different to your second solution ;) When an addressable variable is passed to an `inout` parameter, it is done so by reference (but semantically, it should still be thought of as copy-in copy-out) – so `newNumbers` is passed by reference to `modifying`.

Comment: The error is detected in OP's code at the call site.  At that point, a reference is made to `usedNumbers` so that the inout value can be passed back to it, which prevents `newNumbers` from being modified (same structure). That is what causes the simultaneous access issue.  In the modifying case, I believe the structure inside of modifying is a copy at the time of the call to `popLast(to:)` which avoids the issue.

Comment: @Hamish: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545

Comment: @vacawama https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#inout-arguments :) It certainly was the case that in previous versions of the language, `inout` parameters were done using copy-in copy-out, but now they're compiled as pass-by-references. I can only assume they haven't updated the documentation to reflect that due to the fact that they should semantically still be thought of as copy-in copy-out.

Comment: I don't think a struct containing 2 arrays meets the *value stored at an address* criterium for the reference optimization, so it uses copy in - copy out.

Comment: @vacawama I'm looking at the IR here, and it is passed by reference – https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/ac9372e6bc0b2dd69d4f4f9287328eed if you're interested.

Comment: OP's code now compiles fine as of the version of Swift 4 that ships with Xcode 9 beta 3 :)

Comment: Thanks @Hamish! I updated the answer with this info.